# How should I build my rest api post URI endpoint for a 1:N relationshiop? (nested vs not nested)

Tags: api, rest, one-to-many, endpoint, restful-url

I have been dealing with this problem many times and after reading different articles, I still dont know which is the best approach

Lets say I have this model:

-Author
-Category
-Book

A book cannot exists without an author and a category, so when talking about a post endpoint for a creating a new book, I have fouroptions:

1. myapi/v1/authors/{authorId}/category/{categoryId}/boooks (nesting entities)
2. myapi/v1/{authorId}/{categoryId}/boooks (just the foreign keys as path parameters)
3. myapi/v1/books/?author={authorId}&category={categoryId} (using query params)
4. myapi/v1/books (using a request DTO containing both author and category id)

Which one of these options is the best? Option 1 gives a lot of information about the relations, but it can be difficult to mantain as relationships grow (very long URI)

Options 2 and 3 looks fine to me, but I dont know if it is the proper approach

Option 4 is easier to read and mantain, but it does not provide information about how book i related to author and category

I am open to advice. Thanks!

```
Trying to build a proper and readable post endpoint for a post rest api endpoint
```

Comment: This is probably an opinionated question, but 3 gives you a lot of flexibility. These are essentially filtering options, which you may introduce more of in the future.

Answer (score 0):

#4 in my opinion. URL doesn't have to give information on your data structure

Comment: So would you choose the fourth approach? (/books with a BookDTO containing both autor and category id

Comment: correct, I would choose the option #4

Answer (score 0):

The context of my answer that we are talking about a custom approach, not a standard like OData.

1. ok, if you correct the typos, hard to follow if you mix plural (authors, books) and singular (category) forms.
2. definitely not, hard to guess and remember
3. ok
4. for simple requests like this it does not make sense to use POST or SEARCH, it is better to use them for more complex search

I vote on the 3rd one, because there is no hierarchical relationship between the authors and the categories. I guess one author can post to multiple categories and one category can contain multiple authors, so it is n:m relationship in database terms. For most of the cases I like the 3rd solution, because it is simple. If you have a unique id for the resource, then it is just `{type}s`, `/{type}s?filters={filters}`, `/{type}s/{id}`, `/{type}s/{id}/{property}`. If you have many different resource types, then `{type-group}/{type}s`. Filters can be JSON serialized and URI encoded if you don't care about readability, for machines it is readable after all.

What most people don't grasp, that the webservice is a service, it has operations the consumers call and it is not a data structure. These endpoints identify which operation will handle the request, not which data record will be accessed in the database. The latter one is because we are talking about a certain type of operation, but I can easily write `GET https://example.com/calendar/api/v1/time/now` and it won't touch the database at all.

Answer (score 0):

I will go for the fourth option.

myapi/v1/books (using a request DTO containing both author and category id)

with POST request, using request DTO for sending data is a good solution most of the cases as a rule of thumb.

And importantly, using request DTO, will allow you to use the same api for single creation or bulk creation of books, you just need to send a list in the request DTO for multiple book creation in one api call.